# Tensorflow pip install on mac with python3

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow, pip

I know this has been asked many times, I saw them tried to solve my problem but I can't, nothing works for me.

- I have a mac m1, My os version is BigSur 11.5.1
- My python3 version is 3.8.10
- I have a project folder, which I created my env in there as atai_env
- I ran pip upgrade, my pip version is current which is 21.3.1
- I activated my env and ran `pip install tensorflow` which gives this error;

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
>
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow

- I saw some command as pip install `tensorflow-macos` so I tried it, it seems to install but at the end it gives this `Failed to build h5py` which I tried to install but failed again
- Then I tried to ran pip command given here for python 3.8 -> https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip and it gives below error;

> tensorflow-2.7.0-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_11_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

I am so sick of this :/ I tried to install other versions of python but it always fails. Can someone explain what should I do, I can't believe I spent more than 2 hours on this.
On the tensorflow install page, it seems I should only be running `pip install tensorflow` but that doesn't work

Comment: Btw I checked if my python is 32 or 64 bit. It is 64. I tried to install different python versions and picked the 64 always

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Nothing that I found on google helped. I started over, and decided to try python versions starting from 3.9 with decreasing versions. Finally this command just worked -> `pip install tensorflow` with python 3.7.9 It is so frustrating, cost me a few hours. I wasn't expecting it would be unstable like this. Anyway, if you happen to face it just try to use one of the version 7 even tho tensorflow says it works for 3.7 - 3.9

PS: I am sorry but this is really stupid, it is almost 2022 and we are working on AI with this framework comon :/

Comment: Note: Even if you manage to install tensorflow with this version, it probably will not work with m1. Just go with conda forge or mini forge etc. It is so problematic as of today.

Answer (score 0):

I have MacOS BigSur 11.6.1 running and just created a `virtualenv` with **Python 3.8.12**. Installing *tensorflow* works without any problems:

`pip install tensorflow`

```sh
pip install tensorflow                                                                                                                                           1 err | 8s | voice_assistant py 
Collecting tensorflow
  Downloading tensorflow-2.7.0-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_11_x86_64.whl (207.1 MB)
```

Comment: Didn't work for me, I had to try different python versions and finally it worked with 3.7.9 I tried so many things that I found on google, just waste of time :/ thanks for your answer

Comment: Can you try to do the PIP-Upgrade after activating your env with `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`. Maybe you have already tried it?

Comment: Yes already tried it. And I solved my problem by changing python3 version to 3.7.9 @Michael Boesl

Answer (score 0):

I could successfully install and run TensorFlow from my M1 MacBook Pro. Monterey 12.4. Here's what I did:

#### 1. Install Homebrew first

How typical.

#### 2. Install Anaconda via Homebrew

`brew install anaconda`

Installing Python is a mess and I know most tutorials will suggest to use `pyenv` as the version management tools. I tried that, but didn't work. What worked for me is Anaconda.

#### 3. Download PyCharm

It's a GUI-friendly way to switch between Python versions and environments.

#### 4. Set the Python interpreter inside PyCharm

[image]

Note that I use **Conda Environment**. Note also that the `conda` executable is inside `/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/bin/conda`.

#### 5. Install `tensorflow-macos` from the PyCharm terminal

After doing this, you can `import tensorflow as tf` inside your `.py` files.

Answer (score -1):

You can try upgrading the version of pip.

Comment: Check the 4th point in the post, I've already tried it :/